# FireDAC SQLite backup saves no data

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, firedac

When executing the following code, the database file only has table names. No field names or actual data seems to be getting copied over.

```
procedure TdbModule.BackupDB();
begin
  ADConnection1.Connected := True;
  ADSQLiteBackup1.DatabaseObj := ADConnection1.CliObj;
  ADSQLiteBackup1.DestDatabase := 'd:\dan.sdb';
  ADSQLiteBackup1.Backup;
end;
```

The `dan.sdb` file is being created, it just lacks any backup data. The application displays data and works fine.

Ideas?

Comment: Not related, just a side note, in Delphi, you don't have to include the parentheses `()` at the end of methods like other languages require. If you have no parameters, then you can delete them.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to just close connection to db, call CopyFile(...) for backup, reopen connection to db?

Comment: @ComputerSaysNo It could, but the [SQLite3 backup API was designed to be better](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html): "This procedure works well in many scenarios and is usually very fast. However, this technique has the following shortcomings: Any database clients wishing to write to the database file while a backup is being created must wait until the shared lock is relinquished. It cannot be used to copy data to or from in-memory databases. If a power failure or operating system failure occurs while copying the database file the backup database may be corrupted following system recovery"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a SQLite in-memory database with several TADMemTable / other datasets connected to it using FireDAC LocalSQL ?

If yes, then backup will not copy content of the datasets, because they are represented as SQLite virtual tables. Backup copies only content of the regular tables.

As workaround you should:

- perform CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ... commands for each ADMemTable to copy them to regular tables;
- set ADLocalSQL.Active to False;
- perform backup.

Comment: This is now I had it yes. I have recently changed my design so that the database connection refers to :memory: and I create my tables direct to the memory database. Then using TADTable I can create backups. Works perfectly. Thanks.